# INSERT INTO with SELECT FROM into variable

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to insert data into a table and get the newly inserted data into a variable, so I can call a function with that data.

I have a table called `foo` and a function that inserts data to it called `insert_data_to_foo`.

After inserting the data, I would like to call another function with that data.

I thought, I could just `DECLARE` an array variable and fill it using `RETURNING`.

But I get `ERROR: more than one row returned`

### Source

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "insert_data_to_foo"(entries my_input_type[])
  RETURNS void as
  $BODY$
  DECLARE
    _added foo[];
  BEGIN
    -- insert data
    INSERT INTO foo(message)
    SELECT "message" FROM unnest(entries)
    RETURNING * INTO _added; -- << ERROR: more that one rows returned

    -- call function with _added data
    perform ....
  END;
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I think you will need to use array loop per [Array Loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) and then probably change ` _added foo[];` to ` _added  record;` and in the loop do the `perform` for each iteration.

Comment: Thx @AdrianKlaver. Loop is an option. But i think there is a better solution. Lets see.

Comment: There may be but without knowing what `call function with _added data` means it is hard to say. The issue is  `RETURNING *  ...` is returning rows of data that you trying to assign to a variable that takes a single value albeit an `array`.  Another potential solution involves a CTE in particular the examples shown here [Data Modifying](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver. Yes, the problem is the RETURNING. I don't see how a cte could help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by putting the INSERT into a CTE which can return the rows. Then you can SELECT from that CTE and aggregate the rows into an array:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "insert_data_to_foo"(entries my_input_type[])
  RETURNS foo[]
as
  $BODY$
  DECLARE
    _added foo[];
  BEGIN
    -- insert data
    with new_rows as (
      INSERT INTO foo(message)
      SELECT u.message FROM unnest(entries) as u(message)
      RETURNING *
    )
    select array_agg(new_rows)
      into _added
    from new_rows;
    ...
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was about to answer the question by myself. I used json_agg.